# how to insert some data another form into new contact form in dynamics crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

So, I'd like to insert data that was taken from one form into a new another one.

In my case, 
I have a contact's form. for example, and there is a lookup inside of it.
I can find any account by using the lookup.
thus, I'm intersted in possibility to take some values of fields in an account that I choosed in the lookup and then insert it in the same fields in contact form.

Could we give me advice what methods a should looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OData to get information about the account in the lookup.  The [OData Query Designer](https://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/) and [XrmServiceToolkit](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/) are two excellent, freely available resources out there to do the heavy lifting for you.

A bit of google research with the above and you should have enough to get you started.  If not, shout again.

Comment: Hi, it seems that the good solution. thanks)  I'd like to point one thing, as I got it right, I will get values through https quiryes, right?)

Comment: Yes.  If using the supported methods (such as these) then it will work on https.  It will work on all deployment methods too; Online, OnPremise, IFD, Office365...

Comment: Yes, So finally I managed to create some odata quieryies hovewer I'm trying to solve the next issue ;)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946399/how-to-retrieve-a-fields-value-from-another-entity-in-mscrm-2011