# how to retrieve a field's value from another entity in MSCRM 2011?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I was able to buld such useful **odata** queryies by using **CRMToolsODataQueryDesigner**
however I'm stuck how can I get value from a particular field of a form.

for instance, I make the next **odata** query

```
  http://ServerName/Organization/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$filter=TypeCode/Value eq '121'
```

so, in such way, I found a one note that relates to particular account.
The next step, I wonder how can I get a value of a particular field in that account.

thanks in advance

I tried something like that:

```
var oDataPath = "http:/ServerName/Organization/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AccountSet?$filter=Name eq 'Sample'";
var retrieveRecordsReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
retrieveRecordsReq.open("GET", oDataPath + filter, true);
retrieveRecordsReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
retrieveRecordsReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
retrieveRecordsReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (this.readyState == 4) {
   if (this.status == 200) {
       var retrievedRecords = JSON.parse(retrieveRecordsReq.responseText).d;
        var vehicle = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_address1").getValue();
alert(vechicle);

   }
}
};
  retrieveRecordsReq.send();
```

The trouble with at this step:

```
   "var vehicle = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_address1").getValue();"
```

here, I'd like to get a value of a particular field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var vehicle = retrievedRecords.results[0].new_Address1;
```

Comment: eventially got a box, however, vehicle = "indefined". I checked my Odara query exactly return only one account record

Comment: Can you check what the Schema name for new_address1 is. It needs no be same same case as it is in the settings so it might be new_address1 instead of what Jason suggested

Comment: @Rickard N
thanks, guys, eventially solved an issue! by correct line on a such way. JSON.parse(retrieveRecordsReq.responseText).d; http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2011/12/13/read-records-synchronously-using-json-in-crm-2011.aspx